# Unity. Переключение на объект после создания

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я использую 2D объект `Deck` в качестве колоды для карточной игры, при вызове у которого `OnMouseDown()` поверх него спавнится другой объект `Card`. Как после нажатия на `Deck` мгновенно переключиться на `Card`, чтобы к примеру у него начал вызываться метод `OnMouseDrag()`, не отпуская при этом кнопку мыши?

Comment: Никак! Перетаскивание это продолжение нажатия. Нужно отделить импуты от модели объектов взаимодействия, как это и должно быть по `SRP`! Эдайкий `DeckInput` передающий команды.

Answer (score 0):

Прямого решения, как мне подсказывает опыт, нету. Это не означает что решить ее нельзя. Попробуйте в Deck объекта по которому нажали при OnMouseDown() создавать второй Deck и сохранить его в состоянии первого. В OnMouseDrag() перемещать второй Deck на на позицию мышки при этом первого принудительно оставлять на изначальной позиции.